# How to convert a simple client server TCP program into non blocking one

Tags: c, select, tcp, nonblocking

Hi I was reading about non-blocking calls using `select()` from Beej's guide, but I'm still confused as to how to change my simple client-server code to one that is non blocking. Could anyone tell me what changes do I need to make in the server code as well as the client code for that?

Here's the server code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h> 
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>

void error(const char *msg)
{
    perror(msg);
    exit(1);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
     int sockfd, newsockfd, portno;
     socklen_t clilen;
     char buffer[256];
     struct sockaddr_in serv_addr, cli_addr;
     int n;
     if (argc < 2) {
         fprintf(stderr,"ERROR, no port provided\n");
         exit(1);
     }
     sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
     if (sockfd < 0) 
        error("ERROR opening socket");
     bzero((char *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
     portno = atoi(argv[1]);
     serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
     serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
     serv_addr.sin_port = htons(portno);
     if (bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr,
              sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0) 
              error("ERROR on binding");
     listen(sockfd,5);
     clilen = sizeof(cli_addr);
     newsockfd = accept(sockfd, 
                 (struct sockaddr *) &cli_addr, 
                 &clilen);
     if (newsockfd < 0) 
          error("ERROR on accept");
     bzero(buffer,256);
     n = read(newsockfd,buffer,255);
     if (n < 0) error("ERROR reading from socket");
     printf("Here is the message: %s\n",buffer);
     n = write(newsockfd,"I got your message",18);
     if (n < 0) error("ERROR writing to socket");
     close(newsockfd);
     close(sockfd);
     return 0; 
}
```

Here is the client code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h> 

void error(const char *msg)
{
    perror(msg);
    exit(0);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int sockfd, portno, n;
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
    struct hostent *server;

    char buffer[256];
    if (argc < 3) {
       fprintf(stderr,"usage %s hostname port\n", argv[0]);
       exit(0);
    }
    portno = atoi(argv[2]);
    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (sockfd < 0) 
        error("ERROR opening socket");
    server = gethostbyname(argv[1]);
    if (server == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr,"ERROR, no such host\n");
        exit(0);
    }
    bzero((char *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    bcopy((char *)server->h_addr, 
         (char *)&serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr,
         server->h_length);
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(portno);
    if (connect(sockfd,(struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr,sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0) 
        error("ERROR connecting");
    printf("Please enter the message: ");
    bzero(buffer,256);
    fgets(buffer,255,stdin);
    n = write(sockfd,buffer,strlen(buffer));
    if (n < 0) 
         error("ERROR writing to socket");
    bzero(buffer,256);
    n = read(sockfd,buffer,255);
    if (n < 0) 
         error("ERROR reading from socket");
    printf("%s\n",buffer);
    close(sockfd);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The way `select(2)` makes things non-blocking is by waiting for I/O to become possible without blocking (e.g., when new data is available). When using `select()`, you wouldn't normally have to put the monitored descriptors into non-blocking mode (with e.g. `SOCK_NONBLOCK`), so in a sense `select()` is specifically about *avoiding* having to use non-blocking I/O.

`select()` is used to wait for events on multiple descriptors at once. An *event* here is something that would make it possible to `read(2)` from or  (depending on how you use `select()`) `write(2)` to the descriptor without blocking.

As an example, you could use `select()` to simultaneously wait for new client connections and data from already connected clients in your server (assuming you extend it to handle multiple clients). To do this, you would use `select()` to monitor both `sockfd` and any descriptors you get back from `accept(2)`. Without `select()`, you would have to use some form of non-blocking I/O (or separate threads) instead to avoid getting stuck in e.g. the `accept()` until a new client connects, which would prevent you from seeing data from other clients in the meantime. That would be both messier to implement and also less efficient than sleeping in a single location.

`select()` doesn't do any I/O by itself. It only notifies you when I/O becomes possible without blocking. You pass it a set of descriptors, and it tells you whenever I/O becomes possible on any of them. (And also tells you which descriptors it's possible on.)

In addition to waiting for data on sockets, you could use `select()` to wait for e.g. user input on `stdin` at the same time. There are many different types of descriptors that can be `select()`ed on.

Comment: Hmm, I understand that. But, I still don't know that coding part of it. How do I implement it in my code?

Comment: @MarthaPears: Good, I was afraid I was being confusing. `select()` is about making things non-blocking in a sense too, but the method used is to wait for data (or other events). `select()` doesn't make much sense for your current design, since you're never waiting for many things at once. If you extended the server to handle many clients, then you could use `select()` to wait for data from any of them for example. The way you'd do that would be by passing the set of socket descriptors to monitor (which would be the socket descriptors you get back from `accept()`) to `select()`.

Comment: This is just an example client server on which I first wanted to test the non blocking functionality. What, I really am doing afterwards, has a server a 5 clients, so I think select() would fit into it. So, does this change need to be made both in the server file and the clients file?

Comment: @MarthaPears: Unless your client is waiting for multiple things at once, using `select()` in it wouldn't make much sense. There's no way for the client to "see" that the server is implemented using `select()` either, so it's okay to only use `select()` in the server.

Comment: I think most people would think of `SOCK_NONBLOCK` and `O_NONBLOCK` when hearing "non-blocking", so that might not be the best term to use. Those flags make e.g. `read()` return immediately if there's no data to read, instead of blocking until there's data. `select()` is about making sure that there *will* be data to read (or that the `read()` call won't block at least).

Comment: Actually, in my case, I think, what you mentioned SOCK_UNBLOCK and O_NONBLOCK would also do. In that case, do I just need to add something like: fcntl(last_fd, F_SETFL, O_NONBLOCK);
    fcntl(newsockfd, F_SETFL, O_NONBLOCK); in my server program?

Comment: @MarthaPears: You could either pass `SOCK_NONBLOCK` to `socket()` (easiest) or use that `fcntl()` call, yeah. Non-blocking sockets might not be the best solution though, if you're just waiting for something to happen on a bunch of descriptors.